# Creating conda environment for Python 2 still results in Python 3

Tags: python, conda

I've followed the instructions on [Conda's user guide](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html). Yet when I create a second conda environment in which to use Python 2.7, I find that `python --version` still outputs 3.6. What is wrong?

Here's my bash history

```
conda create -n p2 python=2.7 anaconda
# ...
## To activate this environment, use
##
##     $ conda activate p2
conda activate p2
python --version
# Python 3.6.6 :: Anaconda, Inc.
```

When I run `python2 --version`, though, I do get:

```
Python 2.7.15 :: Anaconda, Inc
```

Comment: <responding to deleted comment> @RaunaqJain : Thanks for asking, but according to the man page, the `-n` option is just the name of the environment. It's arbitrary. Nevertheless, I'll try it now...

Comment: Ya, I deleted that after realising it. Can you give me the output of `which python` when in the environment?

Comment: when you activate the environment do you get (p2) at the beginning of your terminal?

Comment: The output of `which python` is `/home/markham/bin/miniconda/envs/p2/bin/python`

Comment: @ikuamike : yes, the terminal prompt begints `(p2)`.

Comment: Well. I found the problem. Apparently, I had a bash alias shadowing my `python` command. (⁄ ⁄•⁄ω⁄•⁄ ⁄)
(I don't understand why `which python` didn't reveal the alias' location, though.)

Comment: so it works okay now? @JellicleCat

Comment: Yes, thanks, @ikuamike

Comment: Well good. I was about to ask you to change your alias in .bashrc